# Terms and conditions internationalization with links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, conditional-statements

Hi guys i have a question about Internalization and the terms and condition:

in my view i have this:

```
I18n.t("user.registration.form.accept_terms_conditions", :conditions => link_to(I18n.t("user.registration.form.conditions"), page_url('privacy_policy')), :terms => link_to(I18n.t("user.registration.form.terms"), page_url('terms_and_conditions')))
```

and in my it.yml i have this:

```
accept_terms_conditions: "Accetto le %{conditions} e i %{terms}"
  conditions: "condizioni sulla privacy"
  terms: "termini di utilizzo"
```

The problem is that the result is not what i expected, messing the virables.
what i want its just this:

> Accetto le **condizioni sulla privacy** e i **termini di utilizzo**

how should i do this?
Thanks a lot!
Massimo

Comment: Please provide more info: how are the variables messed up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a namespacing problem with your YAML. In this case `accept_terms_conditions` is a namespace so it can't have content directly - it needs a child namespace to contain the content.

For example, you could structure your translation like this :

```
accept_terms_conditions:
  text: "Accetto le %{conditions} e i %{terms}"
  conditions: "condizioni sulla privacy"
  terms: "termini di utilizzo"
```

and the `.t` call in your view would look like this :

```
I18n.t("accept_terms_conditions.text",
  :conditions => link_to(I18n.t("accept_terms_conditions.conditions"), page_url('privacy_policy')),
  :terms => link_to(I18n.t("accept_terms_conditions.terms"), page_url('terms_and_conditions')))
```